# Why isn't AWS's sponsoring being shown on Database Administrators Meta?

Tags: support, meta, site-sponsorship

Has this been just forgotten or is it intentional?
My thoughts are that if you sponsor the site, then it should be shown on the Meta site as well.

See more at: [AWS will soon be sponsoring Database Administrators](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3447/aws-will-soon-be-sponsoring-database-administrators)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't find any mention that the meta site is automatically included in a sponsorship.

According to the post [Which Stack Exchange sites have dedicated sponsors?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/341663/202162) over on the main Meta site only a limited number of sites currently have an active sponsorship.

#### Answering Your Question

> Has this been just forgotten or is it intentional?

I guess it is intentional, as set forth in some legal binding contract. For details please contact [Stack Overflow Advertising](https://stackoverflow.com/advertising) or [Stack Exchange](https://stackexchange.com/about/contact) directly.

Answer (score 5):

Site sponsorships only appear on the main sites not the Meta sites.